# Neo4j time series aggregation query

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

I have a year, month, day, hour, minute graph similar to http://neo4j.com/docs/1.9.4/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html, where a minute may have 0 or more events happen, and an event can only occur once.

I want to be able to build a query to match for frequencies for a period, such as

Were there at least 2 events occurring every 3 hours for the last 7 days.

I can fetch all the events that occurred in the last 7 days and count them by hour:

```
"MATCH (e:Event)-[:occurred]->
         (minute:`Time::Minute`)-->
         (hour:`Time::Hour`)-->
         (day:`Time::Day`)-->
         (month:`Time::Month`)-->
         (year:`Time::Year`)
WHERE  e.occurred_at > #{7.days.ago}
RETURN year, month, day, hour, COUNT(DISTINCT e)"
```

But I do not know how I could extend this query to group the event counts into 3 hourly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would just need to extend the `RETURN` to have the `hour` variable as well:

```
MATCH (e:Event)-[:occurred]->
         (minute:`Time::Minute`)-->
         (hour:`Time::Hour`)-->
         (day:`Time::Day`)-->
         (month:`Time::Month`)-->
         (year:`Time::Year`)
WHERE  e.occurred_at > #{7.days.ago}
RETURN year, month, day, hour - (hour % 3) AS hour_group, COUNT(DISTINCT e)
```

Not that you should get in the habit of using Neo4j parameters.  That means that intead of `#{7.days.ago}` you would have `{start_time}` and pass in a `start_time: 7.days.ago` hash as the second argument when you query in Ruby.

Comment: Updated, I actually realised I am doing what you suggested. I have event counts by the hour for the last 7 days. I actually wanted to have the event counts for each 3 hour block, for the last 7 days.